# Problema con la cantidad de resultados de jtable de java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando eliminar registros pero se me presenta un problema al eliminar varios, pues el siguiente codigo  `int[] rows = datalistado.getSelectedRows();` sólo me regresa una.

Este es mi código:

```
   public void leeRifIdentif(){
         String RIF;
         int cont=0;
         modelo = (DefaultTableModel)this.datalistado.getModel();
            int[] rows = datalistado.getSelectedRows();     
            for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                RIF=((String)modelo.getValueAt(i, 1));
                cont++;
                 try{
                     ps =cn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rif=?");
                     String rif = String.valueOf(RIF);
                     ps.setString(1,rif);
                     ps.executeUpdate();
                     MostrarDatos(false);
                     VaciarCampos();                              
                    }catch(SQLException e){
                         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                   }
           }     
            if(cont == (int)rows.length){
                 CboCampo.setSelected(false);
           }
   }
```

> nota: me regresa sólo un registro y he seleccionado varios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dije antes, mi solucion seria almacenar todos los rif seleccionados. Yo lo haria asi:

1- Hacer uso de la clase LinkedList para almacenar los rif

```
LinkedList<Integer> listaRIF = new LinkedList<>();
```

crear un evento de escuchar al jtable

```
 private void jTable1MousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    int fila = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    listaRIF.add(Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 0)));
}
```

Lo que hará es capturar cada vez que vas seleccionando una celda.

Lo siguiente seria:
Crear un botón "Eliminar" donde recorrerá todo los rif que hayas seleccionado en el metodo anterior.

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    for (int i = 0; i < listaRIF.size(); i++) {
       //haces la eliminacion  como lo planteaste hace un rato
        System.out.println(listaRIF.get(i));

    }

}
```

Comment: listaRIF.add(Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 0))); me da error

Comment: me da error  listaRIF.add(Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 0))); no me agrega a la lista

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto lo tienes mal:

```
RIF=((String)modelo.getValueAt(i, 1));
```

Deberia ser

```
RIF=((String)modelo.getValueAt(rows[i], 1));
```

Con datalistado.getSelectedRows(); estas seleccionando todas las filas MARCADAS, me refiero dandole al Ctrl y seleccionandolas y creo que tu tienes en el campo uno un checkbox y quieres coger las que tienen el checkbox seleccionado, asi que deberia ser algo así:

```
         DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel)this.datalistado.getModel();
        List<Integer> rows=new ArrayList<Integer>();
introducir el código aquí
            //Metemos las filas con el textbox a true en un array
            for(int i=0;i<modelo.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                //Suponiendo que el checkbox es la columna 1(0)
                System.out.println(modelo.getValueAt(i,0));
                if(modelo.getValueAt(i,0)!=null && modelo.getValueAt(i,0).equals(true))
                 rows.add(i);
            }

        for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++){ //Codigo de borrado de cada fila }
```

Ten cuidado con actualizar la tabla antes de borrar todas en la base de datos por que puedes borrar otras filas diferentes a las seleccionadas así que puedes:

1.Borrarlas en la base de datos y al borrar todas actualizar la tabla.
2.Borrarlas con un for al revés desde la ultima fila seleccionada hasta la primera.
3.Borrarlas con un forEach.

Saludos.

Comment: se me complico porque pide iniciliazar la lista y no se como